# Как остановить выполнение функции? ( jQuery, .hover() )

Tags: javascript, jquery

При наведении на квадраты картинки меняются друг за другом с помощью интервальной функции. 
Не могу решить 2 проблемы. 
1. Функция должна запускаться только у того квадрата на который навели. 
2. Функция должна останавливаться если курсор ушёл с квадрата.

Помогите додумать.

```js
$('.block').hover(function(){
    setInterval(myFuncSuper2, 3000);
  });

    // Change pic on hover
    function changePic(i) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            jQuery(".hero-cat_" + i).addClass("active");
            jQuery(".hero-cat_" + i).siblings().removeClass("active")
        }, i * 1000)
    }
    function myFuncSuper2() {
        for (let i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
            changePic(i);
        }
    }
```

```css
.block {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
  position: relative;
  background-image: url="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/34158/e223aed5-4ea8-4e85-bb69-88e207b6c16b/s1200";
  background-size: cover; 
  cursor: pointer;
}

.block img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
}

.block img.active {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">
  <img src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/38069/39782144-fdc6-473f-b757-b8209a2e4b31/s1200"  class="hero-cat_1 active">
  <img src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/225396/aea85590-65df-49b9-b959-d14cefbd9d38/s1200"  class="hero-cat_2">
  <img src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/34158/e223aed5-4ea8-4e85-bb69-88e207b6c16b/s1200"  class="hero-cat_3">
</div>
<div class="block">
  <img src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/38069/39782144-fdc6-473f-b757-b8209a2e4b31/s1200"  class="hero-cat_1 active">
  <img src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/225396/aea85590-65df-49b9-b959-d14cefbd9d38/s1200"  class="hero-cat_2">
  <img src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/34158/e223aed5-4ea8-4e85-bb69-88e207b6c16b/s1200"  class="hero-cat_3">
</div>
```

Comment: А все картинки изначально точно должны быть невидимыми?)

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME поправил. И js поправил, немного не то было.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще говоря, останавливают интервал так, через `clearInterval`:

```
var interval;

$()...on(событие.., function(){
  interval = setInterval(...);
});

$()...on(Другое_событие.., function(){
  clearInterval(interval);
});
```

А явная нумерация классов `class_1`, `class_2` чаще всего бесполезна. У классов же и так есть номер (индекс), который можно использовать. В jQuery этот индекс можно указать, например, через `.eq()`.

```
$('.class').eq(0) // — Первый такой класс
$('.class').eq(1) // — Второй
$('.class').eq(2) // — Третий и т.д.
```

В вашем же случае, код будет выглядеть примерно так (я пробовал внести минимум изменений... не получилось))) *А возможно даже просто через JS было бы легче, чем jQuery...

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/h9u81sex/)

```js
var interval; /* Переменная, чтобы хранить/стирать интервал */
var ImgChangeTime = 2000; /* Время интервала, здесь будет удобнее менять, чем копаться в скрипте */

$('.block').on('mouseenter', function(){/* При входе мышки в блок */
  var block = $(this);/* определяем переменную == этот же блок */

  interval = setInterval(function(){
    /* Осторожно, Бобо!
    Здесь block == уже определенный элемент, в котором находится курсор
    find() — находит классы .hero_cat внутри него 
    .index помогает найти номер элемента с классом .active, среди классов .hero_cat*/
    var index = block.find('.hero_cat').index( block.find('.active') );
    
    console.clear(); console.log('Было: ' + index); /*нашли номер. Проверка*/

    /*Находим еще количество всех картинок, с классом hero_cat*/
    var imglength = block.find('.hero_cat').length;
    
    /* После каждого интервала, если найденный индекс активного класса оказывается равен 
    [количеству классов - 1] (т.е. последний) = ему некуда расти, станет = 0 */
    if( index == imglength-1){
      index = 0;
    } else { index += 1; } /* В остальных случаях, +1 на каждом круге */
    
    console.log('Стало: ' + index);

    /* Сперва удаляем все активные классы */
    block.find('.hero_cat').removeClass('active');
    /* И добавляем его ровно на нужный (следующий) элемент, через .eq(индекс) */
    block.find('.hero_cat').eq(index).addClass('active');
    
  }, ImgChangeTime);
});

$('.block').on('mouseleave', function(){
  clearInterval( interval );/* Мышка покидает блок - интервал стирается */
});
```

```css
.block {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
  position: relative;
  background-image: url("https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/34158/e223aed5-4ea8-4e85-bb69-88e207b6c16b/s1200");
  background-size: cover; 
  cursor: pointer;
}

.block img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
}

.block img.active {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="block">
  <img class="hero_cat active" src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/38069/39782144-fdc6-473f-b757-b8209a2e4b31/s1200">
  <img class="hero_cat" src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/225396/aea85590-65df-49b9-b959-d14cefbd9d38/s1200">
  <img class="hero_cat" src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/34158/e223aed5-4ea8-4e85-bb69-88e207b6c16b/s1200">
</div>
<div class="block">
  <img class="hero_cat active" src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/38069/39782144-fdc6-473f-b757-b8209a2e4b31/s1200">
  <img class="hero_cat" src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/225396/aea85590-65df-49b9-b959-d14cefbd9d38/s1200">
  <img class="hero_cat" src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/34158/e223aed5-4ea8-4e85-bb69-88e207b6c16b/s1200">
</div>
```

P.s. на самом деле, если вам в дальнейшем нигде не нужно использовать скрытые `<img>` - то было бы легче все ссылки сохранить в каком-нибудь массиве, а в HTML оставить одну лишь картинку. При наведении - просто переключать его значение `.src`

P.s.-2: Если параллельно не используются другие библиотеки, в которых тоже может присутствовать `$`, то везде можно заменить слово `jQuery` на `$`. Первое - запасной вариант на случай конфликтов с другими библиотеками.